# How to handle no Internet connection with Ion (android library)?

Tags: android, android-networking, android-ion

I'm using the [Ion Library](https://github.com/koush/ion) (Android Asynchronous Networking and Image Loading) on Android. The typical code to do a generic HTTP petition is similar to this:

```
Ion.with(context)
.load("http://example.com/thing.json")
.asJsonObject()
.setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
        // do stuff with the result or error
    }
});
```

I don't know what to do when there is no internet connection. I'm debugging on my phone with wifi and 3G disabled, and I'm not receiving any exception on the callback. I expect a exception inmediately, I think that it must fail instantly.

How I must manage this scenario? Thanks in advance